# Titanium ScrollView Doesn't Grow When Objects Are Added

Tags: ios, titanium, scrollview, appcelerator

I have a titanium scrollview with the following properties:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    contentHeight: 'auto', 
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});
```

Initially, I don't add quite enough content to it to make it scroll. However, if the user presses a button, it adds a tableview row that should extend beyond the bottom of the screen, making the scrollview scrollable.

However, when the user click's the add button, which should add a row of height 150, a row gets added that is only tall enough to extend to the bottom of the screen, leaving the scrollview still unscrollable.

I tried changing the layout from composite to vertical, which on the surface fixes the problem, but there still seems to be a maximum height and everything after that gets cut off.

How can I add a row to the bottom of the scrollview and actually have titanium add the whole row?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that there is a TableView inside the ScrollView? It sounds a bit like you are adding a TableViewRow to a ScrollView...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `appendRow` method wasn't calling a relayout on UI elements and therefore the scrollview wasn't checking whether it should now be scrollable.

However, changing the method to `insertNewRow` did seem to update the scrollview and it allows scrolling.